# Google Earth looking choppy on Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: kubuntu, google-earth

I just installed Google Earth (V 7.3.3.7786 64bit) on my Notebook running Kubuntu 20.04.1. However, the maps look strangely scrambled and choppy, such as in this screenshot:
[image]

The same issue occurs with Google Earth in the browser (Firefox). Presumably this is some issue with my onboard graphics (AMD Picasso (rev c4))?

Comment: What happens if you zoom **in** further? What happens if you zoom **out**?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Essentially the same. Blockyness persists on all zoom levels -- when the whole globe is visible, the blocks near the pole are wedge-shaped, so it presumably is somehow arranged along the coordinate system.